# Comportamento estranho da função rand()

Tags: php, random

Pela definição na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php#refsect1-function.rand-description)

```
echo rand() // Imprime algo completamente aleatório
echo rand($min, $max) // Imprime algo em um range entre min e max
```

Em um codigo, dentro de um loop, acidentalmente acabei gerando o seguinte `rand($max, $min)` dai observei o comportamento bizarro, ele não gera um aviso falando que o valor do primeiro parâmetro não deve ser maior que o valor do segundo, como se por exemplo eu omitisse apenas um dos valores, que me geraria:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Se eu usar a função `mt_rand` por exemplo, ele me gera o aviso:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- mt_rand(): max() is smaller than min()

Mas com `rand` gerou valores com um comportamento peculiar que me deixou curioso

Testando por exemplo o seguinte codigo:

```
for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++){
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        if($i < 9) echo rand(10,0).",";
        else echo rand(10,0)." | teste -> ".($j+1)."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Obtive mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
3,10,4,5,7,8,4,9,5,2 | teste -> 1
2,2,10,5,9,6,8,2,5,2 | teste -> 2
7,8,4,10,5,7,8,8,5,4 | teste -> 3
9,7,4,3,10,10,9,4,8,4 | teste -> 4
5,8,4,4,3,3,8,10,4,3 | teste -> 5
2,9,9,5,8,4,10,5,10,5 | teste -> 6
8,9,10,2,10,9,10,9,2,8 | teste -> 7
2,6,6,5,9,8,7,6,8,9 | teste -> 8
8,8,7,6,2,5,8,2,9,8 | teste -> 9
5,6,6,4,7,6,3,6,4,4 | teste -> 10
```

E pior! Se você trocar o `rand` pra valores mais próximos, tipo `rand(10,8)`, ele imprime:

```
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 1
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 2
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 3
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 4
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 5
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 6
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 7
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 8
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 9
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10 | teste -> 10
```

Fiz testes nos seguintes emuladores online: [repl.it](https://repl.it), [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/) e [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/) e pude observar que nesses que usam versões mais atuais do PHP isso não ocorre, fui mais a fundo e achei esse emulador que da pra escolher versões antigas: [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) e vi que ate a versão 7.0.14 isso ainda ocorria, tentei procurar alguma coisa no changelog do [php.net](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php) e no repositório oficial do php no [gitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/tags) mas não consegui achar nada a respeito.

Enfim, **claro que isso é um erro, e nem deve existir em código!** Mas me bateu uma curiosidade, o que de fato ocorre com a função `rand`, nas versões antigas do PHP, quando um valor max é menor que o valor min?

Comment: Erro de sintaxe? Isso não me parece um problema estrutural da gramática, então creio que não seja sintático. Erro de semântica?

Comment: A gramática da chamada de chamada de função é `<<fun name>> ( <<lvalue list>> )`; os argumentos são dados pela lista `<<lvalue list>> ::= <<lvalue>> | <<lvalue>> , <<lvalue list>>`, sendo `<<lvalue>>` uma expressão, variável ou constante. Então, para saber que `rand` tem na sua gramática de uso `rand ( <<minor>> , <<major>> )` com a regra não estrutural `<<minor>> lesser than <<major>>`, precisaria conhecer a nível de compilação os valores `<<minor>>` e `<<major>>` e, também, precisaria de uma regra gramatical diferente para essa função. Por isso que falo do semântico

Comment: Na resposta que você passou, creio que seja mais semelhante ao exemplo da divisão de zero por zero, uma operação que por si não faz sentido, mas que está gramaticalmente correta. Não se esqueça: incolores ideias verdes dormem furiosamente

Comment: De qualquer forma, é um erro rs, não quero me focar nesse erro, quero entender o porque ocorre, veja, se eu não tivesse dado atenção a isso, ele gera um resultado bizarro, mas "aceitável", ou seja, poderia ter sido mantido, e eu não iria ter valores aleatórios.

Answer (score 1):

Eu li ambas as documentações, em inglês e português. Posso dizer que tem uma diferença muito grande entre elas. Vide [a documentação em ingles](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) caso não tenha problema com inglês.

Verifiquei também o [código fonte no GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c).

Atualmente, nas versões mais recentes disponíveis, chamadas à função `rand` tornam-se chamadas a `mt_rand`, porém ele trata `max < min` especificamente para evitar chamar `mt_rand` com os valores trocados.

Tem uma observação nos [comentários em inglês da documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#73730) que fala justamente da tendência do PHP em gerar números próximos de múltiplos de 3, mas não entendi o motivo exato disso. Parece que [outro comentário](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#77716) tentou explicar pondo a culpa no intervalo grande de números usados pelo anterior.

Pela implementação de `php_mt_rand_range` em C no [GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/mt_rand.c), se a geração de números aleatório for de baixa entropia nos bits menos significativos, o retorno dado por `(result % umax) + min` (onde `umax = max - min + 1`) vai ser sempre similar quando a diferença entre o mínimo e o máximo também for pequena. Julgar se a função de número aleatório tem alta entropia está além dos meus conhecimentos, entretanto, e ainda mais além do meu conhecimento está julgar se os bits menos significativos tem alta entropia.

Comment: Nota, eu testei o código do comentário naquele emulador que da pra escolher a versão do PHP, o resultado me pareceu bem aleatório em todas as versões >= 4.4.9, o comentário mesmo é de 10 anos atras.